# 401 error code when trying to export powerbi reports

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, powerbi, azure-ad-msal

I am able to get a token using the default scope for powerbi ( "scope" :
"https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default"]  )

With that token, I am able to read the workspaces my user has access to, (  "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups") and the reports information inside each of those workspaces (
"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports/")

But it does not matter if I reuse the same token or just acquire a brand new, if I try to export a specific report, I got a 401 error code.  This is the way I am issuing the requests.get

```
 token_ = <new token or reused from previous get requests> 
 reports = requests.get(  # Use token to call downstream service
      config['reports']+report_id+'/Export',
      headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token_ },)
```

Now, if I go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/getreportsingroup
and sign in (with the same user I am using on my python script).  Get the token from that page and use it on my script. It works, If I use it in postman, it works
I I try to use the token acquired by my script in Postman, I also get a 401 error.  So, yes, my script is not getting the correct token for this particular entry point but it is good enough for the groups and reports entry point.

Is there anything I need to add to the request for the token on this particular entry point?

Thank you very much,
Andres

Here is the full script I am using,  there is also a params.json that looks like this:

```json
{
    "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/1abcdefg-abcd-48b6-9b3c-bd5123456",
    "client_id": "5d2545-abcd-4765-8fbb-53555f2fa91",
    "username":"myusername@tenant",
    "password": "mypass",
    "scope" : ["https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default"],
    "workspaces" : "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups",
    "reports": "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports/"

}
```

```py
#script based on msal github library sample
import sys  # For simplicity, we'll read config file from 1st CLI param sys.argv[1]
import json
import logging
import requests
import msal

def exportReport(report_id,token_):
        result = app.acquire_token_by_username_password( config["username"], config["password"], scopes=config["scope"])
        token_ = result['access_token']
        print(f'Using token: {token_}')
        reports = requests.get(  # Use token to call downstream service
          config['reports']+report_id+'/Export',
          headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token_ },)
        print(f'-reports: {reports.status_code}')

def list_reports(workspace_id,ws_id,ws_name,token_):
    print(f'reports id for workspace {ws_name}')
    for rp in workspace_id['value']:
        if rp["id"] == "1d509119-76a1-42ce-8afd-bd3c420dd62d":
          exportReport("1d509119-76a1-42ce-8afd-bd0c420dd62d",token_)

def list_workspaces(workspaces_dict):
    for ws in workspaces_dict['value']:
        yield (ws['id'],ws['name'])

config = json.load(open('params.json'))

app = msal.PublicClientApplication(
    config["client_id"], authority=config["authority"],
    )

result = None

if not result:
    logging.info("No suitable token exists in cache. Let's get a new one from AAD.")
    result = app.acquire_token_by_username_password(
        config["username"], config["password"], scopes=config["scope"])

if "access_token" in result:
    workspaces = requests.get(  # Use token to call downstream service
        config['workspaces'],
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']},).json()
    ids=list_workspaces(workspaces) #prepare workspace generator
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']}
    while True:
      try:
        ws_id,ws_name=next(ids)
        reports = requests.get(  # Use token to call downstream service
          config['workspaces']+'/'+ws_id+'/reports',
          headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']},).json()
        list_reports(reports,ws_id,ws_name,result['access_token'])
      except StopIteration: 
        exit(0)
else:
    print(result.get("error"))
    print(result.get("error_description"))
    print(result.get("correlation_id"))  # You may need this when reporting a bug
    if 65001 in result.get("error_codes", []): 
        # AAD requires user consent for U/P flow
        print("Visit this to consent:", app.get_authorization_request_url(config["scope"]))
```

Comment: Please show the code you used to get the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, I suppose you didn't grant the correct permission for your AD App used to login your user account in the code, please follow the steps below.

Navigate to the Azure portal -> `Azure Active Directory` -> `App registrations` -> find your AD App used in the code(filter with `All applications`) -> `API permissions` -> add the `Report.Read.All` *Delegated permission* in `Power BI Service` API(this permission is just for read action, if you need some further write operation, choose `Report.ReadWrite.All`) -> click the `Grant admin consent for xxx` button at last.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

Use the `application id` of the access token got from `Get-PowerBIAccessToken` solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for your very descriptive answer.  I am off for today, but tomorrow early in the morning I'll follow your recommendations and report back.

Comment: Good Morning Joy, I already had that permission on my app.  And my user had already being granted the consent by the admin.  That's how I am able to read the reports and workspaces using my script.    These are my current API permissions on the app: Power BI Service:  App.Read.All,  CapacityReadAll,  Dashboard.Read.All, Dataflow.Read.All, Dataset.Read.All,   Gateway. Read.All,  Report.Read.All,  StorageAcount.Read.All, Tenant.Read.All, Workspace.ReadAll.    They are all already granted to my user.

Comment: I edited the original post to include the script and json file I am using for authentication.

Comment: In case it is important:   I got into powershell, and connect to powerbi using my account (Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount),   then I got the token (Get-PowerBIAccessToken -AsString), copy and paste that token into my python script and ran the script.  And then I got a 200 (return code) from the export request.  So, definitely, my user when using the app is not getting the correct kind of token for the export, but it is the correct one for listing workspaces and reports.

Comment: @MisterWalrus Could you show the screenshot of the `API permissions` page of your AD App in the question? And decode the token got from the code in https://jwt.io/, see if the `Report.Read.All` permission is existing in the `scp` claim?

Comment: Good Morning Joy,  I did try to paste it here, I could not.  How could you paste all those images?  I can try to find a free sharing images sites though. Let me try that approach:  https://ibb.co/MphPp7n

Comment: @MisterWalrus The permission looks correct, could you decode the token got from the code like I said above to check the permission?

Comment: Sorry Joy, I am not sure what you want me to do.  I can get the token from the script but how do I decode to check permissions?

Comment: @MisterWalrus Paste your token in this page https://jwt.io, then see if the `scp` claim contains the `Report.Read.All` permission.

Comment: Wow!  I had no idea of that possibility. Thank you so much.  Unfortunately this is what is shown: "scp": "App.Read.All Capacity.Read.All Dashboard.Read.All Dataflow.Read.All Dataset.Read.All Gateway.Read.All Report.Read.All StorageAccount.Read.All Tenant.Read.All Workspace.Read.All",    I see that the scope includes Report.Read.All already

Comment: @MisterWalrus It's so weird, looks it should be correct

Comment: Curiously, the working token (the one provided by using Get-PoserBIAccessToken) shows the following scope:  user_impersonation

Comment: @MisterWalrus What is the `aud` of the working token?

Comment: They are the same. BUT, the client id is different....I don't know if I could try that application_id , but I'll try

Comment: Joy, I did use the appid that came from the correct token and now the python script was able to export the report (return code 200).   I really don't know if this is the right solution but at least I can make it work this way.  If you have any idea, please let me know.  For what is worth, I can't find the right words to tell you how much grateful I am of your help.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Why I can't select  your comment as the correct answer?

Comment: @MisterWalrus There is no such feature, updated your comment in my answer.